# Los shortcodes de wordpress no renderizan

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy desarrollando un tema y le estoy aplicando `shortcodes`, pero en las paginas y en las entradas, me muestra el texto literal en lugar de lo que retorna el `shortcode`.

Estoy usando el codigo que sale en la API.

```
//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Cuando coloco en mi entrada o en una pagina el texto `[foobar]`, me muestra ese texto literal.

No se que pasa, no se si me estoy saltando una configuracion, si es mi entorno, o algo que se me escapa.

Intente el siguiente codigo

```
add_shortcode( 'foobar', function( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
});
```

y tampoco.

single.php

```
<?php 
get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
      <article class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
          <p class="lead"><?php echo get_the_content() ?></p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <?php endwhile; endif ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Te funcionan otros shortcodes como los listados aquí? https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/

Comment: No, no funciona. tambien lo muestra literal, sera mi wordpress?

Comment: Yo creo que el problema está en la forma que muestras el contenido. Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el código de tu single.php (lo relevante)?

Comment: listo, ya lo he editado.

Comment: Si ya vi el error, tenia un <?php echo get_the_content() ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error está en:

```
<?php echo get_the_content() ?>
```

Ya que debes imprimir el contenido del post con:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Esto sucede porque WordPress no le aplica el filtro [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) al llamar a la función [get_the_content()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).